# No such file or directory error when attempting to run shell script upon startup of console

Tags: shell-script, bashrc, cygwin

I'm trying to run a shell script upon startup in cygwin. I have added these commands to my .bashrc file:

```
$ echo 'export MAIN="D:/dev/Main" >> .bashrc
> echo '.MAIN/Env/tpsScripts/devenv.sh $MAIN' >> .bashrc
> echo 'export TPSBUILD_USEMKG=1' >> .bashrc
```

So when I go to restart cygwin. That .sh file should execute and I should see console output. But I don't. Instead I get:

```
-sh: .D:/dev/Main/Env/tpsScripts/devenv.sh: No such file or directory
```

I checked my d drive path: D:/dev/Main/Env/tpsScripts/devenv.sh and sure enough this devenv.sh file exists and is there.

What is going on here? How can I fix this? Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Show us the actual commands that you typed, or the content of your `.bashrc`. I know that you're lying to us because the commands here are not syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cygwin you access drive letters by going through /cygdrive eg:

```
sh /cygdrive/d/dev/Main/Env/tpsScripts/devenv.sh
```

Comment: This did the trick, I edited: > echo '.$MAIN/Env/tpsScripts/devenv.sh $MAIN' >> .bashrc to use sh instead of the '.' replaced it with sh